# Gambler's Ruin - Number of ways to lose at exactly time t (formula explanation request)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains, random-walk

I was trying to figure out the general formula for the number of distinct "paths"/ways a gambler could reach 0 wealth for the first time in exactly t steps, given that they start with wealth = 1, and at each step they gain +1 or -1 with 50/50 probability.

Here are a few simple cases as example (where we ignore even values of t, since there are clearly 0 paths):

t = 1: (-1) -> number of paths = 1

t = 3: (+1, -1, -1,) -> number of paths = 1

t = 5: (+1, +1, -1, -1, -1), (+1, -1, +1, -1, -1) -> number of paths = 2

I tried a number of approaches to find some general formula (mainly dynamic programming), but couldn't seem to find the proper solution. Then, after writing out the values of t and my manually calculated solutions for each (up to 11), I noticed a pattern.

Number of paths = ${t \choose t/2 + 1/2}/t$

That is, the number of paths equals the number of distinct orderings of the wins/losses divided by t. I tested this against a computer program and it seems to have held for a large variety of t values I tested, so I'm assuming this formula is correct.

However, I don't quite understand where exactly this formula is coming from. How would one construct this formula without simply guessing it from a pattern like I did?

Comment: *I was trying to figure out the general formula for the number of distinct... ways a gambler could reach 0 wealth for the first time in exactly t steps, given that they start with wealth = 1*  -- isn't this a ballot problem?  There are many ways to get to this result but the nicest uses the reflection principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem

Comment: ah you're right this is a ballot problem. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recast this in terms of [Bertrand's ballot theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem)  Instead of saying that the gambler loses $k$ times and wins $k-1$ times, we consider an election where the winner gets $k$ votes and the loser $k-1$.  By Bertrand's ballot theorem, the probability that the winner is always ahead, assuming the votes are counted in random order, is $$\frac1{2k-1}.$$  The number of possible orders is $$\binom{2k-1}{k}$$ so the number of possible paths is $$\frac1{2k-1}\binom{2k-1}{k}$$ which is the same as your result with $t=2k-1$.

The wiki article cited above actually mentions your problem.